# how to insert a variable in a middle of a text in vb

Tags: vb.net

for example, how do i insert variable into the text going to written in the text file?

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim message1 As String = TextBox1.Text
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\TestFolder1\test.txt", "how many edges does" message1 "have?"  , True)
        Process.Start("C:\TestFolder1\test.txt")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your variable is of `String` type (like in your case `message1` is a `String`), you could simply use `+` operator:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim message1 As String = TextBox1.Text
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\TestFolder1\test.txt", "how many edges does" + " " + message1 + " " + "have?"  , True)
        Process.Start("C:\TestFolder1\test.txt")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Note that I added `" "` just for convenient of reading. For other data type (for instance `Integer`), you could use `ToString()` method to convert it to `String`, before you added it:

```
Dim message1 As Integer = 5 'Note that this is an Integer now
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\TestFolder1\test.txt", "how many edges does" + " " + message1.ToString() + " " + "have?"  , True)
```

Comment: it worked perfectly... thanks alot and appreciate additional information on integer

Comment: thats sounds great.. im still new to VB and stackoverflow and this question is part of project im working on currently. hope you can help me in near future as well.. :)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to use String.Format instead. It is more readable.

Please refer to this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Public Class Form1
        Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            Dim message1 As String = TextBox1.Text
            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\TestFolder1\test.txt", String.Format("how many edges does {0} have?", message1)  , True)
            Process.Start("C:\TestFolder1\test.txt")
        End Sub
    End Class
```